# Prove or disprove if x∈Z, then $x=⌈\frac{x}{2}⌉+⌊\frac{x}{2}⌋$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove or disprove if x∈Z

$$x=⌈\frac{x}{2}⌉+⌊\frac{x}{2}⌋$$

I'm just unsure how to go about this question and can't find decent examples in my textbook. I'm assuming that the assumption is true based on plugging in arbitrary integers, but I'm unsure how to phrase an explanation.

I was going along this route but wasn't sure if I was getting warmer

⌈x⌉ = n if and only if $n - 1 < x <= n$

$⌈\frac{x}{2}⌉$ = n if and only if n-12

⌊x⌋ = nif and only if n <= x < n + 1

$⌊\frac{x}{2}⌋ = n$ if and only if $\frac{n}{2} <= \frac{x}{2} < \frac{n + 1}{2}$

Comment: You may find it useful to consider two cases (when $n$ is even and when it is odd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is even, we're done. If $x$ is odd, write $x=2k+1$ so the right-hand side is $k+1+k$.

Comment: So write a proof along the lines of:
Assume x is an arbitrary even integer 2k.
2k = ⌈2k/2⌉+⌊2k/2⌋
2k = ⌈k⌉+⌊k⌋
2k = 2k

Assume x is an arbitrary odd integer 2k + 1.
2k + 1 = ⌈(2k + 1)/2⌉+⌊(2k + 1)/2⌋

Comment: @MichaelPascuzzi To deal with one case, yes.

Comment: Ah and then then the odd case is something like
Assume x is an arbitrary odd integer 2k + 1.
2k + 1 = ⌈(2k+1)/2⌉+⌊(2k + 1)/2⌋
2k + 1 = ⌈2k/2 + 1/2⌉+⌊2k/2 + 1/2⌋
2k + 1 = ⌈2k/2⌉+⌊2k/2⌋ + 1
2k + 1 = k + k + 1
2k + 1 = 2k + 1

Comment: I feel a lot better about this now thanks for the help. Any tips for getting better at proofs in general for discrete math @J.G?

Comment: @MichaelPascuzzi Just try to express the cases in algebra.